# Stack content below another in mobile view in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 and I want the image-two class (with all it's child contents in the else conditional) to stack below the "box" class div with the "New Image" contents in the mobile view. Right now it's stacking on top and I want to find a clean way to stack it below it, how can I best do that?

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-5 col-md-offset-0 left-rail">
<div class="tab-content">
    <% _.each(profile.suboffices, function(office, key) { %>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane">
            <div itemscope class="address">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                    <h3>Location</h3>
                    <p itemprop="streetAddress">
                        Address 
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      Details Here 
                    <% if (office.phone) { %>
                        <p itemprop="telephone">
                            Phone Number 
                        </p>
                        <% } %>
                            <a>Contact Agent</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                    <h3>Hours</h3>
                    <p class="hours">
                      Content
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <% if (profile.office_photo)  { %>
                <div class="image">
                    Show this photo
                </div>
                <% } else { %>
                    <div class="image image-two">
                        Show this other photo
                    </div>
                    <% } %>
        </div>
        <% }); %>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
    <div class="box">
      New Image
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the else you could use another div with the inverted condition and put it where you want it to be. So the condition for `image_two` could be:

```
//Below .box
<% if (!profile.office_photo)  { %>
    //Your markup
<% } %>
```

If you want to achieve this with plain css you can use `display: table` for the parent. Than bring the childs in the right order by using `display: table-header-group` for the first, for the second `table-row-group` and `table-footer-group` for a last item.

I made a small example for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/morrisjdev/ntkmhsqq/

Comment: But how do I do the stacking with this in Bootstrap 3 so that this is below the "box" class in the mobile view?

Comment: Bootstrap does not have a feature like this, as I know. But you can use css and `display: table`. I'll Update my answers with more details

Comment: Can you provide an example of how I would write that in my HTML code?